# Firebase sends push notifications every day without active campaigns

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

A week ago I experimented with FCM console and sent push messages to my Android device. But after that many (thousands) of users started to receive pushes every day in 23 h. I suppose, this is because of time zone difference. When I look at Cloud Messaging Reports, I see it really sends data notifications. But I even don't have active campaigns (including planned campaigns). How can it be?

UPDATE

I've got answers from Firebase and AppMetrica (an alternative analytics service) support. They say it is possible the app is not able to handle the data message (`silent notification`) sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw charts in FCM Reports, showing that every day it delivers data messages. Every day it's count slowly raised.

I've got answers from Firebase and AppMetrica (https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/docs/). Firebase support didn't find a problem, but suspected silent push messages. AppMetrica support found a problem. AppMetrica uses FCM to send push messages. I wrote a code for integration of AppMetrica and FCM incorrectly, so silent pushes haven't been handled right. After I unselected a checkbox in settings that **updated tokens via silent push messages**, Firebase charts dropped to zero.